# Provide images to Cordova from Meteor other than app icon

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

In a Meteor project, the app icons and launch screens are provided through the `mobile-config.js` file. I've read the [Meteor docs for mobile config](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs), but it does not talk about how to provide images other than the app icons and launch screens.

I am developing a Cordova Plugin that generates notifications. On Android, a notification needs a small image to show in the status bar. I would like to be able to provide the image through my Meteor app.

Is it possible to edit the `mobile-config.js` file or somehow generating a `Drawable` from the images stored in the `www` folder of the Cordova project?

Comment: I think the solution is to give a URI to the Cordova Plugin so it can get the image through the phone's file system. I've found this solution thanks to this project on Github : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/master/src/android/notification/AssetUtil.java